# Footnote reference for xsl fo

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I'm facing problem in xsl fo "footnote" footnote refrence not align how to align
I want the footnotes to displaying on left align not indented.
Coding are following:-

body text:-

```
"<footnoteref refid="FN0001">1</footnoteref>"any action taken by the Central
Government under the Resolution of the Government of India, Planning Commission
bearing Notification Number A-43011/02/2009-Admin.
```

XSLT:-

```
<xsl:template match="footnoteref">
<xsl:variable name="fnoteid" select="@refid"/>
<fo:footnote>
<fo:inline font-size="70%" baseline-shift="super">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</fo:inline>
<fo:footnote-body>
<fo:list-block provisional-label-separation="2.5mm" provisional-distance-between-starts="10mm">
<fo:list-item>
<fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
<fo:block text-align="right"  text-indent="0pt" margin-left="0pt" font-size="8.5" font-style="normal">
<xsl:value-of select="//footnote[@id=$fnoteid]/footnum"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$fnoteid = 1 to 9000"><xsl:text>.</xsl:text></xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</fo:block>
</fo:list-item-label>
<fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">
<fo:block text-align="justify"  text-indent="0pt" margin-left="0pt" font-size="8.5" font-style="normal">
<xsl:apply-templates select="//footnote[@id=$fnoteid]"/>
</fo:block>
</fo:list-item-body>
</fo:list-item>
</fo:list-block>
</fo:footnote-body>
</fo:footnote>
</xsl:template>
```

my footnote look like

1. Received the assent of the President on March 25, 2016 and published in the

   1. Received the assent of the President on March 25, 2016 and published

      ```
        3. Received the assent of the President on March
      ```

But i want to

1. Received the assent of the President on March 25, 2016 and published in the
2. Received the assent of the President on March 25, 2016 and published
3. Received the assent of the President on March

Comment: Please also include the XML for an example 'footnoteref` and its `footnote`.  What is the purpose of "`test="$fnoteid = 1 to 9000"`"?

Comment: <footnoteref refid="FN0001">1</footnoteref>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem counter-intuitive but the **`fo:footnote` element inherits properties from its ancestor formatting objects**.

So, if a footnote descends from an `fo:block` element (or another block-level formatting object) with `start-indent="1cm"`, the footnote body too will be indented!

To achieve the expected result, modify your template to add `start-indent="0cm"` to the `fo:list-block` element inside the `fo:footnote-body`. Similarly, you will have to "reset" other properties you don't want the `fo:footnote-body` to inherit (`end-indent`, spaces, `font-size`, ...).